# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (20) at non-singleton dimension 2

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have an input tensor `X` with shape `torch.Size([3, 1, 20, 20])` `(batch_size x channels x height x width)` and a target tensor `y` with same shape `torch.Size([3, 1, 20, 20])` now when I use mean square error loss, it gives me a warning:

```
Using a target size (torch.Size([3, 1, 20, 20])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([3, 1]))
```

but input shape is `torch.Size([3, 1, 20, 20])` ?

and then I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (3) must match the size of tensor b (20) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

code:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.l1 = torch.nn.Linear(20 * 20 , 1)

def forward(self, x):
    return torch.relu(self.l1(x.view(x.size(0), -1)))


def training_step(self, batch, batch_nb):

    X, y = batch

    
    loss = F.mse_loss(self(X), y, reduction='mean')
    return loss

def configure_optimizers(self):
    return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.02)
```

can someone help please

Answer (score 0):

Your input is of size [3,1,20,20] but the output of the model (`self`) is of size [3,1] because you pass the input through a fully connected layer and then reshape (`view`) it.

I'd offer code on how to fix this issue but it's unclear what your goal actually is here.

Comment: thanks, my goal is to fit X image to y, like doing regression on image.

Comment: What does output represent? If your target output has the same dimension as your input, then you need to design a model architecture that creates an output with the same dimension as your input. Yours does not do this

Comment: I wanted to replicate what I was doing with ```fit``` function in keras, where it was as simple as using ```fit(image1,image2)``` and used MSE, I wanted to replicate this in pytorch, but I am a bit lost.